# SOLID SRP and FluentNhibernate entities

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, solid-principles

this class is from http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started
it has some logic in it and I think this violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chad_myers/archive/2008/03/07/pablo-s-topic-of-the-month-march-solid-principles.aspx), how do you think, how would you resolve this ?

Another thing that bothers me is why in nhibernate always it is being used IList and not IEnumerable which has less functionality ?

```
public class Store
{
  public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Employee> Staff { get; set; }

  public Store()
  {
    Products = new List<Product>();
    Staff = new List<Employee>();
  }

  public virtual void AddProduct(Product product)
  {
    product.StoresStockedIn.Add(this);
    Products.Add(product);
  }

  public virtual void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
  {
    employee.Store = this;
    Staff.Add(employee);
  }
}
```

Comment: Two questions:

1) What do you think the responsibility of this class should be?

2) Which elements of that code do you think fall outside that responsibility?

It looks pretty clean to me - this class represents information and processes relating to a Store; there's no UI code, data access or other cross-cutting concerns in there...

Comment: well I wasn't sure if it violates the SRP, so that's why I asked this question

Comment: What are the two responsibilities according to you?

Comment: I think that it should have just one reason to change, and also that POCO stuff, it's not POCO cuz it has methods, also from where I copied this code it is written "This entity has a little bit of logic in it to make our code simpler, that's the AddProduct and AddEmployee methods;", so I guess that usually they don't do like that

Comment: Poco's have methods. A store should be a store where you can add products to, not just data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this does not violate the SRP principle. And, as Paco mentioned, it is still a POCO class. POCO does not mean that the object should only contain data.

I would, as you mention, however change from IList<> to IEnumerable<> on my collections and make the setters private (for the collections). That is not a problem for nhibernate to handle. Using those "add" methods is in my opinion the preferred way of handling the collections on your model ([blog post about that](http://mattias-jakobsson.net/Item/50/Promise%20only%20what%20you%20can%20keep)).

Comment: the only problem is that with IEnumerable you won't be able to easily add new element to the collection in that AddProduct method, I think you would have to use linq concat extension or something

Comment: That isn't a problem. You just have the private collection as List<> or something with a add method and the public as IEnumerable<> (described in the blog post I mentioned).